# Windows kiosk / restore functionality

Tags: windows, system-restore

I have a Windows 7 Professional machine used as a kiosk. However, I want to be able to use Microsoft's system restore to basically restore the machine after each reboot.

I believe this will:

1. Revert any changes to files made by the system
2. Still save changes to wired/wireless settings so they do not need to be entered in again

How can I program the computer to:

1. Perform system restore of computer at a specific time of day
2. Restart the system after the system restore completes

Answer (score -1):

See the [detailed instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg176676%28WS.10%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: Steady State does not work for Windows 7. It ended at Vista.

Comment: I know.  If you read that link, you'll see that it tells you how to replicate SteadyState with built-in Win7 features.

Comment: I have, but I don't understand how to use the code it provides. That's why I am asking for help on here.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with shell/vbs ... etc

Comment: @user: So you're hoping someone will write the code for you? Unlikely. It sounds like it's time to learn shell scripting and/or VBS. If you have *specific* problems along the way, feel free to post questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray: No; he's asking for an out-of-the-box solution.  (eg, a Win7-compatible SteadyState)  Since my answer requires code, it doesn't really answer his question well.